# Odd Component.isValid() Behavior

Tags: javascript, lightning-aura-components, lightning

While building a prototype demo, A coworker and I came across some unexpected behavior and I wanted to get some thoughts here.

In our components initialization, we're starting a poller using setInterval. According to the lightning docs, we need to wrap our interval callback code in $A.getCallback() since the interval is outside of the components execution stack.

We're also checking the Component.isValid() when the callback fires because we need to run clearInterval() on the poller in case the component is no longer valid (i.e. no longer on the page).

During our testing, when the component should no longer be valid because the user has navigated to another page, the isValid() check continues to return true. Therefore, we don't have a reliable way of cancelling the interval and it continues on forever. Navigating back to the Lead page where our component is running would start another poller.

Any thoughts? Controller code is listed below.

Controller:

```
({
  initScore: function(component, event, helper) {

    // this is where we could add the configuration
    var DO_POLL = true;

    console.log('initScore called');

    helper.doFetchScore(component);

    var pollInt;
    var pollCount = 0;

    var poll = function() {
      pollCount++;

      console.log('polling for changes: ' + pollCount);

      if(!component.isValid()) {
        return clearInterval(pollInt);
      }

      helper.doFetchScore(component);
    };

    if(DO_POLL) {
      console.log('starting poller');

      pollInt = setInterval($A.getCallback(function() {
        poll();
      }), 3000);
    }

  }
})
```

Comment: By `because the user has navigated to another page` you mean the URL has changed or new components have been loaded in current app or parent component?

Comment: In this case, we changed tabs by navigating to the home page.

Comment: Well, I tried your code and its working for me. Navigating to another tab stops the poller. Although I have trimmed the helper method calls, I hope you are not making recursive setInterval calls from there.